# how to use the read sql query for a file that is in the google drive using google colab? I have tried the below file but it is not working out

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, google-colaboratory

I am also facing the same error. Can anyone please help?

I have changed the directory to the path where the file is located and was able to read the data. But when i use the read sql query statement in pandas i get the error.Below is the ipynb code and the error i am getting.

Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

import os

#cwd= os.getcwd()
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/
!pwd`enter code here`
```

second cell:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# After executing the cell above, Drive
# files will be present in "/content/drive/My Drive".
!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv"
```

Third cell:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv') 
# filtering only positive and negative reviews i.e. not taking into consideration those reviews with Score=3
# SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 500000, will give top 500000 data points
# you can change the number to any other number based on your computing power
# filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 500000""", con) 
cur = con.cursor()
df_bonus = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv')
print(df_bonus)


filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 3000""", con)
```

Error Message:

```
            Id  ...                                               Text
0            1  ...  I have bought several of the Vitality canned d...
1            2  ...  Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanut...
2            3  ...  This is a confection that has been around a fe...
3            4  ...  If you are looking for the secret ingredient i...
4            5  ...  Great taffy at a great price.  There was a wid...
...        ...  ...                                                ...
568449  568450  ...  Great for sesame chicken..this is a good if no...
568450  568451  ...  I'm disappointed with the flavor. The chocolat...
568451  568452  ...  These stars are small, so you can give 10-15 o...
568452  568453  ...  These are the BEST treats for training and rew...
568453  568454  ...  I am very satisfied ,product is as advertised,...

[568454 rows x 10 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1585         try:
-> 1586             cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1587             return cur

DatabaseError: file is not a database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1596 
   1597             ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")
-> 1598             raise ex from exc
   1599 
   1600     @staticmethod

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 3000': file is not a database
```

Comment: Code here is supposed to be *minimal*, among other things; that means, code that comes *after* the error should not be included (it is never executed), as well as irrelevant imports - it just looks intimidating to possible respondents and creates unnecessary clutter (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Reviews.csv is *either* a csv file ( `con = sqlite3.connect('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv')`
*or* a sqlite database (`df_bonus = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv')`. It can't be both.  Conventional wisdom says the file is a csv. Therefore, it cannot be connected to sqlite3, else you will get error `DatabaseError: file is not a database` (or similar). The csv data would need to be loaded into a database before any queries can examine it.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/sqlite-database-with-pandas/) to get you started.